# Deleting an entire row from a Parse class

Tags: android, parse-platform

How can I delete an entire row from my Parse User class in android? I want users to be able to delete their accounts from my application and if they delete their account I want to be able to delete their entire User row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call one of the delete methods on the user object: `delete()`, `deleteEventually()`,`deleteInBackground()`, etc.

Example:

```
ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
user.deleteInBackground();
```

The ParseUser class is a subclass of ParseObject so it has all of the same delete methods. You can look at the API reference [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/?com/parse/ParseObject.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would provide additional feedback for a slightly different situation where you need to delete the user. I used the answer Eric Amorde gave as a starting point, but I had to delete the user when I was running a test. The basic goal was to delete a user from the parse database after the user was registered. This would keep me from having to go in and delete the user every time I ran the test. I initially used the above code Eric Amorde posted within a static method, but was not getting any results. Since I was creating the user during the register process in the background, I had to also delete the user in the background. Someone else may know a better way that I should have used, but below is the code snippet which includes all of what I did while the thread was working in the background.

```
    user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    dlog.dismiss();
                    if (e != null) {
                        /**
                         * Show the error message
                         */
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        /**
                         * Start a new intent for the dispatch activity
                         */
                        Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, DispatchActivity.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

                        /**
                         * Check to see if the username is ParseUser and immediately deletes from
                         * Parse database to allow repeated runs of the RegisterActivityEspressoTest
                         */
                        if(etUsername.getText().toString().equals("ParseUser")){
                            ParseUser registerTestUser = new ParseUser();
                            registerTestUser.getCurrentUser().deleteInBackground();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer can create bugs due to a failure to logout/clear the local datastore subsequent to the delete method.

1) According to Parse's documentation, delete() is not always sufficient to delete AND logout the user.  Sometimes, the user remains logged in via the local datastore even after the delete() call, leading to bugs the next time the user opens the application (or simply the next time the app checks for a current user with the getCurrentUser() method.  Instead, logout must be called in the callback of the delete function like this:

```
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
currentUser.deleteInBackground(new DeleteCallback() {
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        currentUser.logOutInBackground();     
                    } else {
                        //handle the error
                    }
                }
            });
```

It's counterintuitive, because you would think you shouldn't have to logout if the account has already been deleted, but you do.

2) Also worth noting, delete can only be called when the user is authenticated (using either login(), signup(), or getCurrentUser() API calls).  From the Parse documentation:
***Specifically, you are not able to invoke any of the save or delete type methods unless the ParseUser was obtained using an authenticated method, like logIn or signUp. This ensures that only the user can alter their own data.***